# UWP XAML is throwing an unhandled exception when a collection is empty

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, nullpointerexception

I have two `ObservableCollection<T>` and its bonded with two different `ListView` UI.

```
ObservableCollection<Department> deptList = new ObservableCollection<Department>();

ObservableCollection<Teacher> teacherList = new ObservableCollection<Teacher>();
```

User can add or remove items from the collection in the run time.

At some point, if either of the lists is empty, the app freezes and throws an unhandled exception `{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}`

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

**Exception Message**

> Message = "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete.\r\nLayout cycle detected. Layout could not complete."
>
> _message = "A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI."

Here is the code block for `ListView` UI -

```
<ListView Header="Department List"
    x:Name="depertmentList"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind deptList}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    SelectionChanged="depertmentList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Department">
                <StackPanel Margin="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dept}" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SemesterCount}" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Courses, Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView Header="Teacher List"
    x:Name="teacherListView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind teacherList}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="teacherListView_SelectionChanged"
    Margin="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Teacher">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Designation}" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dept}" Margin="1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**C# code for events**

```
        private void depertmentList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (depertmentList.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                removeDept.IsEnabled = false;
                teacherListView.ItemsSource = teacherList;
            }
            else
            {
                removeDept.IsEnabled = true;
                ObservableCollection<Department> t = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
                Department temp = (Department)depertmentList.SelectedItem;
                teacherListView.ItemsSource = from teacher in teacherList
                                              where teacher.Dept == temp.Dept
                                              select teacher;
            }
        }
        private void teacherListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (teacherListView.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                removeTeacher.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                removeTeacher.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Point to be noted, `Teacher` class derives from `Department` class. And if I remove a Department, all the teacher associated with that department gets removed too.

To prevent crashing the app, I had to add a hardcoded garbage item to the list which the user can remove later in run time.

And again if one of the lists is empty, the app crashes. But if there is at least one item in both lists, nothing happens.

Now, my question is How can I resolve this issue without adding any type of garbage item? I want to prevent crashing even if the lists are empty or null.

Comment: I've added the exception too at the second block of code. I found the lines from App.g.i.cs file.

Comment: sorry , this wont help. Hover on "e" in UnhandledException += (sender, e) , and get the exact exception . That would defiantly help.

Comment: Message = "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.\r\nLayout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete."

Comment: {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs} 

_message = "A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI."

Comment: Hope these helps.

Comment: sure, it helps. Can you please post your xaml , and the code where you assign collection to your xaml control .

Comment: Hi! I've added the XAML code

Comment: add code of selection_changed events, and where you assign collection to listview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203724/discussion-between-mahmudul-hasan-and-noorul).

Comment: When I tested your code and tried to remove the items from one of the collection until it's empty, but it worked well, didn't crash. Did you just empty one of the list and the app crashed? Did you do other behavior? In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like an inner layout design. The problem is ScrollViewer to cause loop rendering. You can set a Height to your scrollViewer. For example:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="2" RelativePanel.Below="TeacherFilter" Height="100">
```

or as the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79d27deb-30c2-4270-a27f-3f805e623580/layout-cycle-detected-layout-could-not-complete?forum=wpdevelop) @Noorul shared to set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility as Auto.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="2" RelativePanel.Below="TeacherFilter" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: You are right. It's all about the layout rendering. Fking useless disaster. It already ruined my entire day thinking about the backend code.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a bit obscure. Your problem, while not exactly possible to debug without setting calm and c# is a variation of this.

When one or the other of your lists is empty, then some kind of exception occurs. Do you have any linq query that assumes that something will return? Do you access that something after all?

The problem is just saying that UWP is trying in an infinite loop to reconstruct your UI, something bad happens and it retries.  That is why your application crashed. Because of the infinite loop.

Comment: I have a LINQ operation when an item of ListView which is bonded with Department is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a scrollviewer inside your ListView , or you may iterate through your items, when there is no item in list.

This threads discus about same issue.

[Layout cycle detected, layout could not complete](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79d27deb-30c2-4270-a27f-3f805e623580/layout-cycle-detected-layout-could-not-complete?forum=wpdevelop)

[Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete. Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242888/layout-cycle-detected-layout-could-not-complete-layout-cycle-detected-layout)

Hope this helps.

If you post your xaml code, it will be usefull the diagnose your issue.

Thankyou.

Comment: But none of these explain why its raising this issue :(