# Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete, For Flyout in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, flyout

I have 8 `Grid` rows populated via foreach loops in `Flyout`.

When the content was too great, it started to crash with the obscure 'layout cycle detected' error..

If I remove one row it is working fine.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide a minimum runnable demo? This will help us reproduce your problem. But before you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242888/layout-cycle-detected-layout-could-not-complete-layout-cycle-detected-layout), it looks similar to yours, you can consider using `ListView` to virtualize the internal items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied below style for `Flyout` the it's working fine now.

```
<Style x:Key="FlyoutPresenterStyle" TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value=" Disabled "/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
</Style>
```